# Filing for an EIN number for a Trust

Tags: united-states, income-tax, trusts, estate-settlement

Recently my  mother died and her living revocable trust is now irrevocable. I am the sole trustee and sole beneficiary of the trust. I am also the executor of her estate.

I need to file for an  EIN number for her irrevocable trust. To avoid having to file an
estate income tax return and a trust income tax return, I am thinking I should make the  trust the 645 election for the trust. I can do that when I file for the EIN number for the trust. However, the election cannot be changed later. I am thinking the best thing for me to do is not make that election when I file for the EIN number. Instead, later this year, assuming I want to make the 645 election, I can file form 8855 for the trust.

Please comment.

Comment: Form 8845? Indian employment credit?... Anyway, what's your question? This is something I'd suggest taking to a licensed tax adviser, but if you're the trustee and the sole beneficiary of the trust and the executor and the sole beneficiary of the estate - I don't really see a problem.

Comment: @littleadv Good catch. There is a typo in the post. It should say form 8855. I will update the post.